# Fabric material (coloured)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, materials, photorealism

Does anyone know an idea to accomplish this from the picture?

[image]

(source: emancipath by Zeitguised)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a wave texture except use no ondulations. Put texture coordinates to object (so it will use a triplanar texture space).